# Como inserir um Cliente com javascript em HTML5

Tags: javascript, html5

```js
var clientes = [];

function classClientes(nro, nome, sexo,dataNasc) {
    this.nro = nro;
    this.nome = nome;
    this.sexo = sexo;
    this.dataNasc = dataNasc;
}



function criarCliente() {
    var numeroCliente = document.getElementById("txtNumero").value;
    var nomeCliente= document.getElementById("txtNome").value;
    var sexoCliente = document.getElementById("txtNome").value;
    var dataNascCliente = document.getElementById("dataNasc").value;

    var repete = 0;

    if (!isNaN(numeroCliente) && !isNaN(nomeCliente) && !isNaN(sexoCliente)) {
        for (var j = 0; j < clientes.length; j++) {
            if (clientes[j].nro == numeroCliente) {
                clientes[j].nome = nomeCliente;
                clientes[j].sexo = sexoCliente;
                repetido = 1;
            }
            if (repetido == 0) {
                var novoCliente = new classClientes(numeroCliente, nomeCliente, sexoCliente, dataNascCliente);
                clientes.push(novoCliente);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Preciso inserir um novo cliente quando o utilizador preencher o formulário(código abaixo) como faco isso utilizando uma função javascript e chamando a função num botao do HTML5 dentro da form que se encontra o formulário?

Código da form com formulário(HTML5):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-pt">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="novoCliente">
        <form action="#">
            <label for="lbNumero">Número:</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtNumero" style="width:250px" /><br />
            <label for="lbNome">Nome:</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtNome" style="width:250px" /><br />
            <label for="lbSexo">Sexo:</label>
            <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="masculino">Masculino
            <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="feminino">Feminino <br />
            <label for="lbDataNasc">Data Nascimento:</label>
            <input type="date" id="dataNasc" /><br />
            <input type="button" id="criarCliente" class="botaoOperacao" value="Criar" onclick="javascript: criarCliente();" />
            <input type="reset" id="cancelar" class="botaoOperacao" value="Cancelar"/>
        </form>
    </div>
  
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Podes explicar melhor onde queres "inserir um novo cliente"? Criar no HTML mais uma div `<div id="novoDoente">`? dentro do formulário já existente? numa base de dados? Explica melhor o que queres fazer para podermos ajudar melhor...

Comment: não estou guardando numa base de dados...as informacoes irão se perder a cada re-load da pagina html, era mesmo para conseguir trabalhar melhor com o javascript visto que tenho alguma dificuldade

Comment: coloco aqui a minha tentativa

Answer (score 1):

Segue abaixo uma das maneiras de se faze-lo:
P.S: Não se preocupe com o HTML em si, pois resolvi aplicar um *layout responsible*, o importante mesmo é o JavaScript

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var clientes = [];

var txtNumero = document.getElementById("txtNumero");
var txtNome= document.getElementById("txtNome");
var rbSexos = document.getElementsByName('rbSexos');
var txtDataNasc = document.getElementById("txtDataNasc");

var tmplLinha = document.getElementById("tmplLinha");
var tbody = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
var btCriarCliente = document.getElementById("btCriarCliente");

isNullOrWhiteSpace = function (str) {
    return !str || str.trim().length == 0;
}

btCriarCliente.onclick = function () {
    var cliente = {};    
    var sexo = ""
    var novaLinha = document.createElement('tr');    
    for (var i = 0; i < rbSexos.length; i++) {
        if (rbSexos[i].checked) {
            sexo = rbSexos[i].value;
        }
    }

    cliente = {
        Numero: parseInt(txtNumero.value),
        Nome: txtNome.value,
        Sexo: sexo,
        DataNasc: new Date(txtDataNasc.value),
    }

    if (isNaN(cliente.Numero) || isNullOrWhiteSpace(cliente.Nome) || isNullOrWhiteSpace(cliente.Sexo) || isNaN(cliente.DataNasc.getTime())) {
        return;
    }

    for (var indice in clientes) {
        if (clientes[indice].Numero == cliente.Numero) {
            return;
        }
    }

    clientes.push(cliente);

    novaLinha.innerHTML = tmplLinha.innerHTML;
    for (var indice in novaLinha.childNodes) {
        var celula = novaLinha.childNodes[indice];
        if (celula.nodeType == 1) {            
            switch(celula.dataset.column) {
                case "Numero": celula.innerHTML = cliente.Numero.toString(); break;
                case "Nome": celula.innerHTML = cliente.Nome; break;
                case "Sexo": celula.innerHTML = cliente.Sexo; break;
                case "DataNasc": celula.innerHTML = cliente.DataNasc.toDateString(); break;                
            }
        }
    }

    tbody.appendChild(novaLinha);
    return;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="#">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-3 columns">
            <label for="lbNumero">Número:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="small-9 columns">
            <input type="text" id="txtNumero" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-3 columns">
            <label for="lbNome">Nome:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="small-9 columns">
            <input type="text" id="txtNome" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-3 columns">
            <label for="lbSexo">Sexo:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="small-9 columns">
            <input type="radio" name="rbSexos" value="masculino" />Masculino
            <input type="radio" name="rbSexos" value="feminino" />Feminino
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-3 columns">    
            <label for="lbDataNasc">Data Nascimento:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="small-9 columns">
            <input type="date" id="txtDataNasc" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-3 columns">   
        </div>
        <div class="small-9 columns">   
            <input type="button" id="btCriarCliente" class="button small" value="Criar" />
            <input type="reset" id="btCancelar" class="button small" value="Cancelar"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Numero</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Sexo</th>
            <th>Data Nasc.</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>

<script id="tmplLinha" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <td data-column="Numero"></td>
    <td data-column="Nome"></td>
    <td data-column="Sexo"></td>
    <td data-column="DataNasc"></td>
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
.row label {
    text-align: right;
    padding-top: 8px;
}

.row .columns {
    padding: 0px 1%;
}

.row input[type="radio"] {
    margin: 12px 0px !important;
}

table {
    margin: 0px 1% 8px 1%;
    width: 98%;    
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxjnu0k2/5/)

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi a parte do javascript que é relevante. Aparentemente AP quer entender com criar uma objeto cliente e inserir os valores nesse objeto. Como se "cliente" fosse uma classe. Em que parte da sua resposta esta sendo criado um cliente?

Comment: Pois bem, eu realmente deveria também ter abordado este aspecto, assim que possível faço uma correção na resposta. Em todo caso esta resposta ainda é útil para ele, pois a intenção maior dele é se familiarizar com Javascript

Comment: @renan, a resposta está retificada.